# reverse the string

Tags: python

I have a content of strings and I have to reverse the order using python.
the content is

1. Python
2. Java
3. microsoft

Answer (score 25):

If you want a new list:

```
a = ["Python", "Java", "Microsoft"]
b = a[::-1]
# b is now ["Microsoft", "Java", "Python"]
```

or

```
a = ["Python", "Java", "Microsoft"]
b = list(reversed(a))
# b is now ["Microsoft", "Java", "Python"]
```

If you want to modify an existing list:

```
a = ["Python", "Java", "Microsoft"]
a.reverse()
# a is now ["Microsoft", "Java", "Python"]
```

If you want a list where each of the individual strings has had its characters reversed:

```
a = ["Python", "Java", "Microsoft"]
b = [x[::-1] for x in a]
# b is now ["nohtyP", "avaJ", "tfosorciM"]
```

The reason why using slice notation with `a[::-1]` returns a sequence that is the reverse of `a` is because slice notation works like this:

```
sequence[start:end:step]
```

since you specify `step` to be -1, that means that it works backwards through the sequence one by one, which is in effect the reverse of the sequence. (`start` and `end` being omitted uses their default values, i.e. the entire sequence.)

Comment: Actually, reversed returns a generator; you'll need to use list(reversed(a))

Comment: -1: Way too complete for answering someone else's homework for them.

Comment: @S.Lott: The way I see it, this is a basic enough question that it deserves to be answered in a way that promotes exploration if the person in question is actually interested in learning. If they're not interested in learning, answering a simple question like this for them is not going to help them in the long run, so it won't really make a difference.

Comment: What is the default value for the end index? Running 'python'[5:0:-1] only returns 'nohty' without the 'p'?! The only value for end I found to get the full string was -6 or smaller. Any clarification?

Comment: To specify the extreme values, you can just omit them - the default values are the extreme beginning and extreme ending positions.

Comment: What's the explanation for `a[::-1]`? Why `a[::0]`, for example, don't work? And what `::` means in python?

Comment: @Tom: It's extended slicing syntax. The *full* slice syntax for Python is `sequence[start:end:step]` (as noted near the end of the answer); step is how the index is changed in between items in the slice. It defaults to `1` (just putting every item from the original list into the slice, in order), but setting it to `-1` makes it go backwards through the portion of the sequence, just like setting it to `2` would make it only take every 2nd item.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ["Microsoft", "Java", "Python"]
>>> l.reverse()
>>> l
['Python', 'Java', 'Microsoft']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

the most comprehensible option for sequences is to use "reversed", but the result is always a list, so for a string you could either use it and convert it to a string again by joining the elements, or use a slice with negative index (this later being more efficient, I guess):

```
s = "abcd"
reversed(s) #-> ['d','c','b','a']
"".join(_) #-> 'dcba'

#or

s[::-1] #-> 'dcba'
```

Comment: Everytime I see that slice method it makes me warm and fuzzy inside. So elegant!

Answer (score -1):

```
public class StringRev {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // text is containing dummy/ Test string
    String text="ReverseToString";
    //StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    // In this line I am creating the object of StringBuffer
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

    // using a for loop in decreasing order from length-1 to 0
    for(int i=text.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
    // getting the character using index and appending in String buffer.
    sb.append(text.charAt(i));

    }
    // converting StringBuffer value to String
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
}
//output will be "gnirtSoTesreveR"
```

Comment: Please add little explanation for future visitors.